Probability of success changing with time with initial probability of success
The setup for this question is I have some data for events in which the outcome is either a success or fail, and this chance of success depends on time. Broadly, each trial has an immediate non-zero chance to succeed (unknown) and then this probability increases as time goes on, with an assumed asymptote at probability 1 as t approaches infinity.
To give an example, my data could have t=30 seconds with a failure, t = 200 seconds with a success, and t = 0 seconds with a success.
So far I’ve considered a model of the form
y = (a+1) - b^(-t)
Where a is the initial success probability, and b is the probability increase in some way, but I have no clear understanding behind what b represents, it’s not like it’s “the probability doubles every x seconds” or similar.
I suspect an adaptation of an exponential would work but I couldn’t make one up that worked in my trial and error.
Are there any well known models that do this already? I did some of my own research but couldn’t find anything, any pointers gratefully accepted!

Why not use a logistic regression with a smoothing spline for time?

Consider exploring your data so you can discover what might be a reasonable model.  Plotting total number of successes by accumulated time, smoothing that (perhaps with a concave-upwards curve), and differentiating the result will help you estimate how the success rate has evolved.

Thanks for your fast responses :). I will look more into splines and logistic regression, and see if I can find a nice function for the cdf!

This process is not described by a single CDF!
